# Cannot ping a single website when I am logged into my account

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, dns, ping

I am having an issue connecting to my website. When I ping `sample.com` the server, I IP address I get is `192.168.0.12`, but when I do an `NSlookup`, I get the correct IP. When I switch user account or go to the recovery mode, the name of site is resolved correctly and I can get to it.

Note that I am trying to access my website from the outside world, not from the local network.

I tried:

`dscacheutil -q host -a name sample.com`

and I got:

```
name: sample.com
ip_address: 192.168.0.12
```

To solve the issue I tried deleting the preferences from the library and resetting the NVRAM:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache

sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder

launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

But the name is still resolving wrong. I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: Do you have an entry for `sample.com` in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: It worked, thank you for saving the day! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have an entry for `sample.com` in `/etc/hosts`.

Entries in `/etc/hosts` take precedence over DNS. In your case, DNS is properly configured (`nslookup` returns the correct IP), but `ping` will use the information in `/etc/hosts` instead. This is also true for any CLI command like `curl` or `wget` and most apps ([some apps](https://superuser.com/questions/723703/why-is-chromium-bypassing-etc-hosts-and-dnsmasq#723732) don't appear to honor `/etc/hosts`.)

Note that the host name specified in the command must match an entry in `/etc/hosts` **exactly**, for example:

```
192.168.16.3   myserver.mydomain.com
```

will direct `ping myserver.mydomain.com` to try to reach `192.168.16.3`, but `ping myserver` will query DNS with whatever default domain is configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

For more information on `/etc/hosts`, see `man hosts` and this Wikipedia [article on `/etc/hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). For more information on `/etc/resolv.conf`, see this Wikipedia [article on `resolv.conf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf).